# need iFrame to not move when other part of page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, scroll, mobile-safari

in my asp.net application I have a page that has a header, then in the body of the page a display of items that a person can choose. When someone chooses an item, an iframe apears on the right side of the body and shows details about the selected item. The iframe size and position is set using the size of the screen. In all desktop browsers - I am able to fix this using the below javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = scroll;
</script>
```

and here is the javascript function scroll

```
function scroll() {
    var divT = document.getElementById('searchframe');
    var divD = document.getElementById('detailframe');

    if (document.body.scrollTop > 80) {
        divT.style.top = document.body.scrollTop
        divD.style.top = document.body.scrollTop

        document.getElementById('detailframe').height = '100%';
    }
    if (document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
        divT.style.top = 75
        divD.style.top = 75
    }
}
```

The scroll function is not even being called when testing using  http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/ - an adobe air ipad simulator. I was able to tell this by placing alerts, which pop up on every other browser and even in this simulator except for the scrolling function. In other browsers, placing an alert at the window.onclick line shows the alert, but on safari mobile the alert is not shown - meaning the window.onscroll event seems like it isnt even being triggered. Thank you for your help.

edit - i can also capture the scroll event using any of the below lines in all browsers, except for mobile safari

```
window.onscroll = scroll;
document.onscroll = scroll;
document.addEventListener("scroll", scroll, false);
```

Comment: Do you realise you are missing semicolons at the end of several lines?

Comment: yes, this was done as well as a few other lines (that dont matter really - policy before I post anything online) were removed - I could also set the window.onscroll to a new function that simple alerts hello world - and it still does not call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to do this in javascript?

Css:

```
position:fixed;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
```

does not work?

Comment: I don't have to do it in javascript, but that is how its currently done across the whole site. Let me try this and see if this will work.

Comment: i could do this using css, this would require a lot of time and effort due to the misuse of CSS in this (inherited when i started working here) application. javascript would be quicker to add on (as this application is just about finished with and will be completely redone). If not, will have to redo multiple pages CSS

Comment: just realized, would prefer not to do using CSS, depending on the scroll top, the size of the height of the iframe changes which I dont think could be handled using css

Comment: Hmm... do you have tried it with a real device? Maybe it is a bug of this emulator?

Comment: thats what I am thinking, I should be able to get my hands on a real device today to test.

Comment: the scroll resize is working when scrolling stops, which is when the onscroll event hits on the actual device. sorry for posting too soon

Comment: This is a known behavior at safari mobile as google told me. Nice to see a problem solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was only due to the emulator, actually works on device.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('iframeID').style.top = intVal;`